# Synchronize multiRunnable

Tags: java, synchronization, runnable

I have 3 Runnable tasks

```
    PeriodRunnable runnableJob1 = new PeriodRunnable(driver, bolgaria);
    PeriodRunnable runnableJob2 = new PeriodRunnable(driver, egipet);
    PeriodRunnable runnableJob3 = new PeriodRunnable(driver, turc);

    runnableJob1.run();
    runnableJob2.run();
    runnableJob3.run();
```

I set 'synchronized' for my object

```
public class PeriodRunnable implements Runnable{
    private final PeriodCountdown counterdown;

    public PeriodRunnable(WebDriver driver, PeriodTour periodTour) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.periodTour = periodTour;
        counterdown = new PeriodCountdown(driver, periodTour);
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized (counterdown){
            counterdown.runCounter();
        }
    }
}
```

but my runnableJobs's starting work all together. What i'm doing wrong, tell me please?

Comment: Your code is running the tasks sequentially in the same thread. Please clarify what behavior you expect.

Comment: @PerHuss I want to start a second runnable after the end of the first runnable and so on

Comment: You _are_ running them sequentially. Don't let the fact that they are runnables trick you, you are calling the three methods one after another, so there is no concurrency involved in your code...

Comment: @PerHuss can you give an example?

Comment: From the code you have shown so far you are not starting any new threads and just running sequentially within the same thread. Are you perhaps starting threads within `PeriodCountdown.runCounter()`? In that case these threads are not synchronized in any way. Perhaps if you share your code for `PeriodCountdown` as well?

Comment: ofc , check the source of PeriodCountdown here http://rgho.st/6Nrdz7sr2